# How do I know that the current user can access a given security key?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

On my current Dynamics AX project, I must add a field group in a form, and protect this group by a given security key. For people with no access to this security key, I must display a replacement text.

How can I test that the current user has the right to access the security key, so that in this case I can hide the replacement text ?

Comment: I see that someone downvoted this. To explain the need of asking this question on SO, I must precise that a Google search didn't help me. 
It seems that security keys in Dynamics AX are a well-documented functionality if you use them statically, but not to use them programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to find whether user has the right to access the security key:

```
SecurityKeySet securityKeys; 
AccessType     accessType; 
; 

securityKeys = new SecurityKeySet(); 
securityKeys.loadUserRights(curUserId()); 
accessType = securityKeys.access(securityKeyNum("YourSekurityKey")); 
info(enum2str(accessType));
```

Comment: Thank you. Tested OK, that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use `hasSecuritykeyAccess(securityKeyId securityKeyId, AccessType neededAccessLevel)` method.

```
if (hasSecuritykeyAccess(securityKeyNum(YourSecurityKey), AccessType::Delete))
{ 
    info('Access granted');
}
else
{
    info('Access rejected');
}
```